# Different behaviours for document.write in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, document.write

So I've done quite a bit of digging into why certain JS will work fine in certain browsers. My problem at the moment is how exactly Chrome handles document.write when the code for writing to the DOM is in a function. Here's my code, it's a simple text form resulting in a pop-up.

From the first page;

```html
<form name="webPage"">
  Please type anything over 5 characters: <input type="text" name="txt2" ><br/>
  
  <input type="submit" name="b2" value="Confirm" onClick="validate2()">
  </form>
```

from the functions java file

```js
function validate2() {
 var valTxt = document.webPage.txt2.value;
 if (valTxt==null || valTxt==""){
  alert("Field cannot be empty!");
  return false;
 }
 if(valTxt.length<5){
  alert("You must enter at least 5 characters!")
  return false;
 }
 if(valTxt.length>5) {
  openWin(valTxt);
  return true;
 }
 }
 
function openWin(txt3){
 var myWin= window.open('mypopup.html', 'myWin', 'width=300,height=300');
 myWin.document.open;
 myWin.document.write('<p>this is text</p>' + txt3);
 myWin.document.close();
}
```

and then the final popup window html file has nothing really in it, just a blank HTML5 template. This code works fine in Firefox, but not so in Chrome. I feel having this really pretty basic example of 2 different browsers working different could help a lot of people. Thanks.

Comment: why do you need `document.write`? if you just want to insert elements into the page, please do it the right way using `document.createElement` and `document.body.appendChild`, Also, if you can get away without using popup windows, everyone will thank you.

Comment: `myWin.document.open;` - should this be `myWin.document.open();` - though, `document.write` (even in frames/popups/etc) is so last millennium!

Comment: yall know how college profs are yall, i cant wait to look into whatever yallz are talkin about but for now im just doin things his way so I don't drown in a whole other bunch of stuff so I can stay sane in other subjects too lol but thankyou